# How to host independent URL in Flutter mobile App?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using one IP based URL of my hosting in my flutter app or all data fetching operations. E.g. "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". I do not have purchase any domain and don't wanna purchase any domain due to limited budget. My question is. What if after releasing app I need to change hosting? Is there any way / suggestion that I can have flexible URL that won't affect if I change hosting. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about using a free domain name? If it is for testing or learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, you can use Firebase Config to send the url from firebase to your app. And if in future url changes, change it from firebase config. And firebase config is absolutely free. firebase config is really easy to set up in flutter project.

[Firebase config pub](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config)

Comment: Thank ou so much Siddharth. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: it's much easier to purchase a static IP hosting. There's a ton of them starting at $5/month

Comment: Alex, thanks for reply but domain costs $10 for year and it would be cheaper than spending $5/month. I would prefer free solution if any.